# C++ Attempting to write a program that takes in emails from a .dat file and exports them to a separate .dat file/

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to write a program that given a message containing words and email addresses on one .dat file, will take only the emails and ignore the lines of conversation.  I have no idea how to do it, honestly.  The main problems being that my program can't find the file I'm trying to read from, I don't know how to only get the emails (something using the @ I'd say), and I don't know how to make it export.  Any help is appreciated.

Here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>                      //For file I/O

using namespace std;

 int main()
{
char inChar;
ifstream inFile;

inFile.open("mail.dat");
if (!inFile)
{
    cout << "Can't open the input file.";
    return 1;
}
inFile.get(inChar);
while (inChar != '\n')
{
    cout << inChar;
    inFile.get(inChar);
}
cout << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

At this point though, I'm not worried about getting the emails or exporting.  I'm just trying to find out why it won't read from my file.  Does it need to be somewhere specific?

Comment: You might want to add the failing code to the question so people can see what you've already accomplished.

Comment: at this point, I have to ask: what *do* you know?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider an interpreted language for something like that. It makes life so much easier:

Python:

```
emails = []
with open("first.dat","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split();
        for word in words:
            if word.find('@') != -1:
                emails.append(word)

with open("second.dat","w") as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(emails))
```